# Make combination of two fields unique in my collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following Mongoose model:

```
var Test = db.model('Test', db.Schema({
        one: { type: String, required: true },
        two: { type: String, required: true }
    },
    { strict: false })
);
```

It has two required fields,`one`and `two`, and `strict:false` because there can be other fields with undetermined names.

I would like the *combination* of `one` and `two` to be unique. That means there could be multiple documents with the same `one` or the same `two`, but none of them should have the same `one` **and** `two` combination.

Can this be achieved with Mongoose?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can enforce a **[unique constraint on compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#unique-compound-index)**, and you can do this in Mongoose using the **[`index()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)** method of the schema, which defines indexes at the schema level:

```
var testSchema = db.Schema({
    "one": { "type": String, "required": true },
    "two": { "type": String, "required": true }
}, { "strict": false });

testSchema.index({ "one": 1, "two": 1}, { "unique": true });
var Test = db.model("Test", testSchema );
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same thing if "two" is a ref to another schema ? thanks

Comment: What is this value `1` being provided in `"one": 1`?

Comment: @AkashTomar 1 represents ascending order

Comment: @chridam I have done what you said, but none of works. Here are my question. How to make a real unique on compound indexes?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324015/mongodb-compound-index-unique-if-a-and-b-both-are-same