# mongodb compound index unique if A and B both are same

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There are many similar questions but none of them solved my question :(

[How to index multiple unique data fields in a single document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179085/how-to-index-multiple-unique-data-fields-in-a-single-document-in-mongoose)

[MongoDb create unique index on a field not in all documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094484/mongodb-create-unique-index-on-a-field-not-in-all-documents)

[Make combination of two fields unique in my collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742224/make-combination-of-two-fields-unique-in-my-collection)

My item schema is here

```
{
    NamespaceId: {
        type: ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    Pattern: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: ''
    },
    Key: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    Value: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    CreatedBy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Comments: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: ''
    },
    IsBanned: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
    Status: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}
```

Now, I have following documents in my collections

```
{
    NamespaceId: 123,
    Key: 'first key',
    Value: 'first value',
    W: '1'
},
{
    NamespaceId: 456,
    Key: 'second key',
    Value: 'second value',
    W: 2
},
{
    NamespaceId: 789,
    Key: 'third key',
    Value: 'third value',
    W: '3'
}
```

I want `NamespaceId` **and** `Key` **and** `Value` are unique. So I create a compounded unique for above collection.

```
ItemSchema.index({
    'Key': 1,
    'Value': 1,
    'NamespaceId': 1
},{unique: true })
```

From my thoughts, following document can insert into because there no same indexes exist in collection.

```
{
    NamespaceId: 123,
    Key: 'second key',
    Value: 'first value'
}
```

But mongoose(nodejs sdk of mongodb) tell me:

```
"BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: configservice_test.configservice_items_tests index: NamespaceId_1 dup key: { NamespaceId: ObjectId('5f2aaabd4440bb566487cf70') }"
```

Mongodb found that `NamespaceId` has already exists so it just throw an exception without checking left `Key` and `Value`.

Which are different from Mysql on `index` concept.

My workaround is to create a new single unique column which value is composed by `NamespaceId, Key, Value` like `123_first_key_first_value`.

Can my needs be achieved by Mongoose?

Comment: @PrathapReddy I'm using https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-index, a third party mongodb sdk, docs said it will pass to createIndex

Comment: Got it... Read about the same. The only issue I could think of is, if there is any unique index already present in DB on `NamespaceId`. Hope you have already debugged in that direction 

Comment: @PrathapReddy why you have deleted your comments, incomplete comments  will misleading people came to here :(

Comment: Sorry... I thought it's miss from my end. I found out later in mongoose docs about what I said hence deleted it since it's irrelevant here.

Comment: @PrathapReddy never mind:), Could you help me to solve this question? I have stuck in there for a while...

Comment: I could only think of 2 things. 1) As I posted in my previous comment (Already existed unique index on that field). 2) The type (ObjectId) of `NamespaceId`. Could you try changing it to String/Number and try the insert again. Apart from these two, I couldn't find any issues here

Comment: @PrathapReddy After change type to String from ObjectId, it's said "BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: configservice_test.configservice_items_tests index: Value_1 dup key: { Value: \"value1\" }"

Comment: Couldn't get the exact issue, you can try few debugging steps like 1) To check if the `compoundIndex` created properly in DB. 2) Make sure there are no `unique indexes` on the individual fields. 3) And few options suggested as per [docs in case of above error](db.collection.bulkWrite/#examples). 4) Try only `single insert` instead of bulk insert etc... Try to post answer if you found any viable solution. Thanks 

Comment: @PrathapReddy I found that if I createIndex use mongo shell db.configservice_items_tests.createIndex({NamespaceId:1,Key:1,Value:1},{unique:true}) instead of creating  using mongoose Schema.index(), It works as normal ;(

Comment: Is it? Then you can try debugging at the start of you application for any [index creation errors](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) - `<Model>.on('index', function(error) { console.log(error.message); });`

Comment: @PrathapReddy error is always undefined :(, I found that mongoose will not create indexes even if I use Schema.index(), But I use mongo shell to create index, all works! I don't know why

Comment: @PrathapReddy I have solved. See answer later!!

Comment: @PrathapReddy view my anwser for a quick look :). Thank you! great greet from China!

Comment: Welcome . Thanks for your answer. Please try accepting after the grace period to save someone else's time in similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer by myself.**

**You Must create Index before create model**

**whole half day to solve it, tired :(**

The following codes cause bugs

```
this.model = mongoose.model(item_collection, ItemSchema)
ItemSchema.index({
    'Key': 1,
    'Value': 1,
    'NamespaceId': 1
},{unique: true ,background: true})
```

Instead of the following not

```
ItemSchema.index({
    'Key': 1,
    'Value': 1,
    'NamespaceId': 1
},{unique: true ,background: true})
this.model = mongoose.model(item_collection, ItemSchema)
```

Comment: The docs example is similar to your working answer BTW. `animalSchema.index({ _id: 1 }, { sparse: true }); var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);`. (Ofcourse it gives error but the order is correct). Good find though 

Comment: @PrathapReddy yes, but I ignored codes order which caused a bug...